# most elegant way to create a javascript popup?

Tags: javascript

Is there a more elegant way of creating a JavaScript popup?

```
<head>
<script>
function myPopup() { window.open( "http://www.google.com", "myWindow", "status=1, height=300, width=300, resizable=0" )
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" onClick="myPopup()" value="popup">
</body>
```

Comment: most elegant way is - never create a popup

Comment: haha, it's for a music player...client request

Comment: the most elegant way will be to create an overlay on the same page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery UI has a great [modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) plugin that is easy to use.

Comment: Can I insert widgets into the dialog boxes? I couldn't find anything about that on the site.

Comment: @Steven Yes you can place whatever html you want inside the dialog, look at the [modal form example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) to see a use case with inputs.

Answer (score 2):

```
<head>
  <script>
    function myPopup(){ 
        window.open("http://www.google.com", "myWindow", 
                "status=1, 
                 height=300, 
                 width=300, 
                 resizable=0"
        );
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" onclick="myPopup()" value="popup" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest, pure html/css.

Using the `details` element toggling capabilities, and the selector `details[open]`:

```css
details > p {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background: lightcoral;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

details[open] {
  position: fixed;
  width: 33%;
  transform: translate(calc(50vw - 50%), calc(50vh - 50%));
  outline: 10px #000000d4 solid;
  transition: all 2s linear
}

details[open] summary::after {
  content: '❌';
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Project</summary>
  <p>Save project<button>Save to file</button></p>
  <p>Publish<button>POST</button></p>
  <p>Update<button>Update</button></p>  
</details>


<details>
  <summary>Another Popup</summary>
  <p>Powered by html<input></p> 
</details>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you're trying to achieve... you could look at Modal Dialogue forms.

jQuery does this http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ for examples.

Comment: Do you know if widgets can be inserted into those dialog boxes?

Comment: Within them you can do whatever you want... i usually use an AJAX request to populate it.

Comment: Actually, for your interest, I have done something similar, using jQuery and http://flash-mp3-player.net/players/js/ to play audio.

Answer (score 0):

That is how I open a modalDialog

```
function showModalDialog() {

        window.showModalDialog('HizmetSuresiUzatma.aspx', 
                               '', 
                               'resizable: no; 
                                scroll: No; 
                                dialogWidth:640px; 
                                dialogHeight:350px');

     }
```

after a button click on a page called `HizmetListesi.aspx`.I write the JS code on that aspx file then call it with

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "hizmetYenileTahsilat", "showModalDialog()", true);
```

on aspx.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

**A GOOD working code with NO crashes.**

Simple and **what makes this code better** is that you can use it in a JavaScript file separately and have it fairing to more then one file with the same popup size even though its different pages on popups.

**Javascript**

```
// Popup window code
function MyPopUp(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(
        url,'popUpWindow','height=454,width=580,left=0,top=200,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="JavaScript:MyPopUp('MyDirectory/Page.html');" title="My PopUp For You">My PopUp</a>
```

**NOTE:** You can also use this as onload in body for example `<body onload="JavaScript:MyPopUp('MyDirectory/Page.html');">` and it will aslo work on `onmouseover` and others... though I do not advise this unless you want to piss off the clients visiting your page.

Answer (score 0):

The modern way using [Dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) which is a new native HTML element that simplifies creating dialog prompts such as pop-ups and modals. With built-in browser functionality like focus management, tab tracking, and keeping stacking context.

```html
<dialog id="dialog">
    <p>Hi, I'm a dialog.</p>
    <button onclick="dialog.close()">OK</button>
</dialog>
<button onclick="dialog.showModal()">Show the dialog</button>
```